# Are there any benchmarks on J2MEPolish converting a J2ME app to Android?

Tags: android, java-me, porting, j2mepolish

[J2ME Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org) claims to support [porting of existing J2ME applications to Android](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/platforms/android.html). Has anyone tested the quality of such a port. How reliable is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their website (and my own experiences) it works ok. You don't have as much access to the raw Android api's and the access you would normally get from writing android code.

Using j2mepolish for porting most games and some basic applications seems to work pretty well. For any thing more complicated ie file access, contact access IMHO it would be better to write native android applications.

http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/platforms/android.html